# save binary fields to folder?

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to use binary fields in openerp, but instead of save them to the database as usual, I'd like to save to file system (folder). I could use a char field to store the path but, is there a way to implement the upload and download for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A module which was developed in version 6 may help you to select path for saving files instead of storing in db as binary.

check out   [web gallery module](https://www.odoo.com/apps/6.0/web_gallery/)